# Why can't i use an attribute containing mysqli object?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

i kinda faced a problem recently that i wasn't able to figure out its solution .
I have a core class that contains the follow code in its constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->runDatabaseConnection();
    $this->fetchSettings();


}

private function runDatabaseConnection()
{
    global $config;

    $this->db = new mysqli($config['db']['server'], $config['db']['user'], $config['db']['password'], $config['db']['name']);
    $this->db->set_charset($config['db']['charset']);

}
```

As you can see i stored the object in an attribute called "db"

After that , I made a method in the same class that runs a given query:

```
public function query($queryStr)
{

    return $this->db->query($queryStr) or die($this->db->error.($this->debugMode ? '<br><b>Query: </b><i>'.$queryStr.'</i>' : ''));

}
```

Now outside class, When i use something like:

```
$studentsQuery = $core->query("SELECT * FROM ".TP."students");
```

$studentsQuery variable seems to be a boolean value and not the ressource that i was expecting , So what am i missing ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a result of boolean expression.

```
return $this->db->query($queryStr) or die());
```

So what I assume you wanted to do was

```
public function query($queryString)
{
    $result = $this->db->query($queryString);
    if (!$result) {
        die(...);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but does "return $result;" return a ressource ?

Comment: a saved the result of `$this->db->query()` into a `$result` variable, which I then return. So either ther result of `query()` was `false`, and then it will `die()`, or it was a resource, which is returned.

Comment: Thank you sir , It worked fine now , I understand why it didn't work before , Best regards .